# Does the "general public" include business entities?

Tags: united-states, business, legal-terms, finance, sec

Specifically regarding securities laws in the United States, there is often terminology that says:

> ... must not be marketed to the general public...

The definition of "marketed" I understand and believe it has more to do with financial security markets as opposed to brochures and other common-parlance examples of "marketing" as a part of communication.

But specifically I would like to know if "general public" is limited to individuals, or if there is legal precedent to expand the definition to corporations, partnerships, etc.

Answer (score 1):

My experience has been that in the context of securities laws,  the term ***general public*** *includes* but is *not limited to* business entities of all types.

If you reason it through, you should agree that this must be the case. This is because, as a practical matter, there is no way to separate business entities from individuals when it comes to marketing and solicitations. This is because ***one person*** can be a business entity (corporation, LLC, etc.)